# Airflow Kubernetes executor keeping the tasks in queued state, airflow 2.6.1

Tags: kubernetes, airflow, docker-desktop

I have setup airflow 2.6.1 locally and k8s cluster locally using docker desktop.My use case is to test sample image with kubernetes executor and I am trying to execute dag with Python Operator and Kubernetes Pod Operator. Both operators are launching pod and pod is successfully completed still the airflow task stuck in queued state and not progressing at all. scheduler log says event success for pod dk-kube-pod-op-test-dks-python-task-9697896s I have provided all the details used.Thanks in advance!

```
Dag code
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator import KubernetesPodOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from kubernetes.client.models import V1ContainerPort
default_args = {
    ‘owner’: ‘airflow’,
    ‘start_date’: datetime(2023, 6, 22)
}
dag = DAG(
    ‘dk_kube_pod_op_test’,
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None
)
def test():
    print(“printed test successfully!!“)    
python_task = PythonOperator(
              task_id=‘dks-python-task’,
              python_callable=test,
              dag=dag)
pod_op =  KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id=‘dks-kube-pod-task’,
    name=‘dks-primeno-pod-test’,
    image=‘prime-numbers:1.0’,
    in_cluster = False,
    dag=dag,
    get_logs=True
)
python_task >> pod_op
```

```
airflow.cfg
[core]
executor = KubernetesExecutor
[kubernetes_executor]
pod_template_file = /****/prime_numbers_deployment.yaml
namespace = default
delete_worker_pods = False
worker_pods_creation_batch_size = 1
cluster_context =  docker-desktop
in_cluster = False
kube_config_path = /****/dks_kube_config
service_account_name = airflow-serviceaccount
```

```
pod template
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: prime-numbers-pod
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: prime-numbers
    image: [repo-name]/prime-numbers:1.0
    command: [“python”, “prime_numbers.py”]
```

```
Pod output is
k logs dk-kube-pod-op-test-dks-python-task-9697896s
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
23
29
31
37
41
43
47
```

```
pod description                              node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age   From               Message
  ----    ------     ----  ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  11m   default-scheduler  Successfully assigned default/dk-kube-pod-op-test-dks-python-task-9697896s to docker-desktop
  Normal  Pulled     11m   kubelet            Container image “[repo-name]/prime-numbers:1.0” already present on machine
  Normal  Created    11m   kubelet            Created container base
  Normal  Started    11m   kubelet            Started container base
```

```
scheduler logs
[2023-07-04T11:30:52.526+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:241} INFO - Skipping event for Succeeded pod dk-kube-pod-op-test-dks-python-task-h9ikd6up - event for this pod already sent to executor
[2023-07-04T11:30:52.527+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:768} INFO - Patched pod TaskInstanceKey(dag_id=‘dk_kube_pod_op_test’, task_id=‘dks-python-task’, run_id=‘manual__2023-07-03T10:17:36.535270+00:00’, try_number=1, map_index=-1) in namespace default to mark it as done
[2023-07-04T11:30:52.530+0530] {scheduler_job_runner.py:677} INFO - Executor reports execution of dk_kube_pod_op_test.dks-python-task run_id=manual__2023-07-03T10:17:36.535270+00:00 exited with status queued for try_number 1
[2023-07-04T11:30:52.536+0530] {scheduler_job_runner.py:710} INFO - Setting external_id for <TaskInstance: dk_kube_pod_op_test.dks-python-task manual__2023-07-03T10:17:36.535270+00:00 [queued]> to None
[2023-07-04T11:baskinrobbins:47.684+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:553} INFO - Found 1 queued task instances
[2023-07-04T11:32:47.739+0530] {kubernetes_executor.py:553} INFO - Found 1 queued task instances
[2023-07-04T11:33:46.685+0530] {scheduler_job_runner.py:1548} INFO - Resetting orphaned tasks for active dag runs
```

```
kuberntes version
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.27.2
Kustomize Version: v5.0.1
Server Version: v1.25.9
WARNING: version difference between client (1.27) and server (1.25) exceeds the supported minor version skew of +/-1
```

Tried multiple options available nothing worked